# Why is my image mask in iOS is so low-resolution (blocky)?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage, mask, cgimage

I am trying to apply a layer mask to a `UIImage` using `CGImageCreateWithMask` but the mask over the image is coming out very low resolution and appears blocky.

This is the code I'm trying ([link to github](https://github.com/BlakeBarrett/mskr-iOS/blob/073dbf5ce57fd821de024b862a82845f03149d57/mskr/DetailViewController.m)) but I don't know what's wrong.

```
- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {

CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage;

CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, true);

CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);
return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];   
}
```

Here's what it looks like in the end. 
My mask is a transparent PNG with an alpha channel (the circle in the screen-shot).

[image: mskr fail]

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks for any/all help.

Comment: Incase it helps; the mask is a 1024x1024px alpha-transparent PNG and the image is a user-cropped JPG selected from the camera-roll.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your mask is getting resized to fit the passed image and thus the jagged edges.

From the docs for `CGImageCreateWithMask`

`If the mask is not the same size as the image specified by the image parameter, then Quartz scales the mask to fit the image`

If that is not the case check the scale properties of the image and mask.

Answer (score 0):

I was never able to figure this out.
It was probably something wrong with how the iOS runtime was interpreting the alpha-PNG I was using. After saving the mask as a JPG everything started working w/o any code-changes.

I find this very strange since the exact same mask files worked on both Android and WindowsPhone.

I assumed that my PNG files should work ([as documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html)) but there must have been an encode setting that was incompatible with `CoreGraphics`